# Time series forecast ARIMA in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, forecasting, arima, swift-pythonkit

I've a time series with few entries (not enough to ML) and I need to forecast some (more than one) future entries in an iOS app. I tested in Python with statsmodels ARIMA model and works fine but I don't find any method in iOS or external library/framework to do statistical time series forecast like ARIMA...
Any hint?

Comment: If you know so much about ARIMA or whatever, perhaps, you should create a library for yourself.  I am afraid this isn't a place where you seek information on existing libraries or tutorials.